# How can I get Nextcloud running on my server?

Tags: mysql, server, mariadb, vps, nextcloud

I ran into problem while installing nextcloud on my vps. Everthing worked exept the creation of an admin user via browser.

I keep getting the error message:
`Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'nexcloudu'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I dont know what to do my admin user config looks like this:[image: Admin-Creation]

And yes I have a password created for the user.

In MariaDB I havent accept remote logging, but I guess its localhost so no need for it.

Thanks in advance, hope smbdy can help me!

I dont know what to do my admin user config looks like this:[image: Admin-Creation]

And yes I have a password created for the user.

In MariaDB I havent accept remote logging, but I guess its localhost so no need for it.

Thanks in advance, hope smbdy can help me!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If you know a root or privileged user account you can [reset the password](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-password/).

Comment: This has nothing to do with nextcloud, actually. This is a generic issue you have with your db setup. I suggest you remove the "nextcloud" tag.

Comment: Often when using MySQL or MariaDB on the local system it helps to use the loopback ip address instead of the name "localhost" (so `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: You could check yourself what the actual issue is by opening an interactive session on your VPS and connecting to the database server using the command line client.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have your own Nextcloud but cannot connect to your database because the password is wrong. The "database password" needs to be the password you probably entered in a (similar) code like this:

```
 CREATE USER 'nextcloudu'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_here'
```

Is this the right code? If you need help with password reset, all you have to do is write!

Also make sure that the database names and usernames are entered correctly!